# Remove an element from array and replace with 0?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

> `public static void remove (int[] arr, int toRemove)`
> "It should remove the value toRemove from the array. The remaining elements should just be shifted toward the beginning of the array. (The array's size will not change). Since the array will now have one fewer element in use, the original last element should just be replaced with 0. If there is more than one occurrence of toRemove in the array, only the FIRST occurrence should be removed. If the array has no elements, it should just have no effect".

So far, I have this:

```
public static void remove(int[] arr, int toRemove) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == toRemove) {
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
            arr[toRemove] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a main method with an array with its contents: `[3, 5, 7, 8, 12, 2]` and a call saying `remove(array, 5)`. However, my array prints out `[3, 7, 7, 8, 12, 0]`, when it should print out `[3, 7, 8, 12, 2, 0]`.

Can someone let me know what I have wrong and explain it?

Comment: So your code finds that arr[1] is 5, sets it to arr[2], which is 7, and then for some reason you set arr[5] to zero. You don't shift any of the other elements.

Comment: Two things - You're replacing the index of whatever the `toRemove` element is with 0, instead of the actual last element, so in your case, you're removing `arr[5]` (which in this case coincidentally happens to be the last element), and you're not accounting for multiple occurrences of `toRemove`.

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger

Comment: @ManishGiri I am only supposed to remove the first occurrence and then the program ends. And since it's a loop, doesn't that mean it's going to set all the current indexes to the next indexes (i + 1) shifted to the left? I believe I still don't follow though on how to shift all the other elements.

Comment: What if you have many times the value `toRemove` in the array?

Comment: Your loop will currently remove all occurrences of `toRemove`, because it doesn't check if a first occurrence has already been removed. What you can do is - 1. loop through the array once to find the index of the first occurrence of `toRemove`, 2. loop through the array again (stopping before the last element) **starting from this index** and shift elements down, and 3. set the last element to zero outside the loop.

Comment: @Cid Thank you sir, that cleared up for my array to change [3, 5, 7, 8, 12, 2] to change the 5 to a 0. But how do I shift all the elements to the end of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach, similar to what I described in the comments above.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class main
{
    // tip: arguments are passed via the field below this editor
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = {3, 5, 7, 8, 5, 12, 2};
        remove(arr, 5);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [3, 7, 8, 5, 12, 2, 0]
    }

    public static void remove(int[] arr, int toRemove) {
        int idx = -1;
        // determine first occurrence of toRemove
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i] == toRemove) {
                idx = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        // if not found, return
        if(idx == -1) return;
        // shift other elements down
        for(int i = idx; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
        }
        // set last element to 0
        arr[arr.length-1] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: could we communicate? I know I have no right to ask, bur I do want to be good at coding, but there are some things I have a difficult time understanding. I need to be explained concepts in an elementary way. I have a coding project I need help on if you're up to help a fellow learner. My email is nguyen_david1949@yahoo.com. Thank you for even reading!

Comment: @Manash Giri I just emailed you actually sir.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two indexes:

fromIndex is the one that go on the array.

toIndex is the place that the item need to be.

```
public static void remove(int[] arr, int toRemove) {
    int toIndex = 0;
    for(int fromIndex = 0; fromIndex < arr.length; fromIndex++) {
        //paste number only if its not 'toRemove'
        if(arr[fromIndex] != toRemove) {
            arr[toIndex] = arr[fromIndex];
            toIndex++;
        }
    }

    //Fill the rest with 0
    for (; toIndex < arr.length; toIndex++)
        arr[toIndex] = 0;
}
```

this works if there are multiple indexes with the value of toRemove

Answer (score 0):

You should use `System.arraycopy`.  It's fast.
Try this.

```
public static void remove(int[] arr, int toRemove) {
    for(int i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == toRemove) {
            System.arraycopy(arr, i + 1, arr, i, length - i - 1);
            arr[length - 1] = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int[] a0 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    remove(a0, 0);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a0));
    int[] a4 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    remove(a4, 4);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a4));
    int[] a5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    remove(a5, 5);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a5));
    int[] a6 = {0};
    remove(a6, 0);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a6));
    int[] a7 = {};
    remove(a7, 0);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a7));
}
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0]
[]
```